# How to replace only digits in math mode with Minion Pro in PDFTeX?

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, minionpro

I'm using MinionPro for my document, but only for text, whereas the default font is used for math mode:

```
\usepackage[onlytext,lf]{MinionPro}
```

However, I would like to have numbers, i.e. digits 0-9, in math mode displayed in MinionPro. I know there are ways to do it with XeTeX, but how can I do this with pdfLaTeX?

I'm aware there is `mathastext` package, but I cannot configure it to apply only to digits, and not also to letters. Any ideas?

I'm not looking for obvious solution, such as `$\text{0}$`, which would require to manually change all numbers to text.

Comment: One way to do this would be to declare MinionPro as a math alphabet, and use a command such as `$\mathmp{7}$`.

Comment: Would do you mean by "declare MinionPro as math alphabet"? Note that I do not want to change letters, or any other character, just digits.

Comment: I do not have that package to test, but the general approach is to declare MinionPro as your `digits` math alphabet with `\DeclareMathAlphabet`, then insert ten commands like ```\DeclareMathSymbol{0}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`0}```.